# Unable to start FastAPI app with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi

The `api` container stops due to the `exited with code 2` error.

```bash
api-1 exited with code 2
...
```

My `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  api:
    image: python:3.9
    restart: always
    command: ["python3", "Main.py"]
    build:
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./api
        target: /app
    ports:
      - 17002:17002
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./api/requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./api /code/app
CMD ["python3", "/code/app/Main.py"]
```

File structure:

```
docker-compose.yaml
api
  Dockerfile
  Main.py
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: run `docker-compose logs` and see the logs. Check for messages that could be causing the container to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete almost all of the Compose settings.  Leave behind only:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    # restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 17002:17002
```

Your system will also be in a slightly broken state; run

```bash
docker pull python:3.9
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

The `command:` and `volumes:` override things in the Dockerfile, and aren't necessary.  If the Dockerfile is correct (and it looks reasonable to me) then, inside the image, the current working directory is `/code`, the default command runs the script `/code/app/Main.py`, and the contents of the host's `./api` directory are copied there.  The `volumes:` mount makes a second unnecessary copy of the code in `/app` in the running container filesystem, and the `command:` override tries to run `Main.py` out of the current direcory instead (still `/code`); the file isn't there (it's in `/code/app`)  and that's why you get the startup error.

`image:` in the Compose file has what here is an unfortunate interaction.  If you have both `build:` and `image:`, the `image:` specifies the name of the image that is built (imagine setting it to a Docker Hub name for your application, for example).  When you specify `image: python:3.9`, you actually overwrite the Docker Hub Python image (locally on your system) with what you've built locally, so then when your next build starts `FROM python:3.9` it actually amends your previously-built image.

`restart: always` does exactly what it sounds like.  One of your problems is that your application is crashing and immediately restarting, and commenting out this line will give you some space to debug the container without it going into an infinite restart loop.